# How to solve complex Simultaneous Linear Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Find $a$ and $b$

(1) $a[(1+\sqrt{5})/2] + b[(1-\sqrt{5})/2] = 1$

(2) $a[(1+\sqrt{5})/2]^2 + b[(1-\sqrt{5})/2]^2 = 2$

Is there a smart method to solve this Simultaneous Linear Equations ?

Thanks you guys!

Comment: Like for any linear system, [Gaussian pivoting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) will do. Or, since it's a 2x2 system, [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) is fine. Also, don't forget there are nice relations with golden ratio $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2$. For instance, $\phi^2=\phi+1$, or $-\frac 1{\phi}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2$ This will help simplify your computation.

Comment: Also, are you trying to find coefficients when solving $u_{n+1}=u_{n}+u_{n-1}$ ? If it's so, you can also use the case $n=0$ in $u_n=a\phi^n+b(-1/\phi)^n$, not only $n=1$ and $n=2$ as you seem to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $\varphi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, so that
$$
\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}=1-\varphi
$$
and your system becomes
\begin{cases}
\varphi a+(1-\varphi)b=1\\
\varphi^2 a+(1-\varphi)^2 b=2
\end{cases}

Multiply the first equation by $1-\phi$ and subtract; now
$$
a(\varphi(1-\varphi)-\varphi^2)=1-\varphi-2
$$
shouldn't be difficult to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}, \beta=\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$. Since we have ${\alpha}^2=1+\alpha, {\beta}^2=1+\beta,$ we have
$$a(1+\alpha)+b(1+\beta)=2.$$
Then, you can get $a+b=1$. And?